# VimeoExtractor gives "Video has restricted playback" error

Tags: android, exoplayer, vimeo

I have application in which i want to play vimeo videos in exo player. so using vimeoExtractor i have played video in exo player after extracting it.

```
VimeoExtractor.getInstance()
                                                             
  .fetchVideoWithIdentifier(mainUrl, null,new OnVimeoExtractionListener() {
                                                   
     @Override                                                                       
     public void onSuccess(VimeoVideo video) {
        Set<String> qualityList = video.getStreams().keySet();
        //....                             
      }
     @Override
      public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
           Log.e("TAG", "onFailure: " + throwable.getMessage());
      }
 });
```

but for private or any video which is unlisted not getting played and it throws error that "Video has restricted playback"

I have tried passing the accesstoken and call the api [https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{videoId}](https://api.vimeo.com/videos/%7BvideoId%7D) and get the url after passing the access token but in return also i get the same url which i already have but doesn't work.

so anyone please help me to solve this problem